# Setting session properly in zend controller action on AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I have an ajax call like following:

```
$.post("/user/signindo",{'username':username,"password":password},function(data){
//doing something with the response
// Now I need to access the session variable
<?=echo("$_Session['id']")?>
}
```

and the action in the controller looks like this

```
public function signindo()
{
$_Session['id'] = 1;  // this value is assigned dynamically when the user logs in
// example of setting session to 1
}
```

The weird thing is that, once the user signs in, the value is assigned with the correct id... Next time I login with the different user,  the ID remains the same from the previous user... Next time when I login with the 3rd user, I get the ID of the 2nd user... If you guys understand me what I'm trying to say? What am I doing wrong here?? How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's due the fact that `$.post` is asynchronous, and the javascript function is called before the session is set, hence the old id.
When you use `$.ajax` it should work.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/user/signindo',
    data: {'username':username,"password":password},
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        // maybe do something with data
    }
});
```

You could also return the id in the PHP function and and access it through the `data` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with [EagleEye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6251886/eagleeye)

You will get session value in data, but you can use $.post jquery call..

```
<script>
$.post("/user/signindo",{username:username,password:password},function(data){

     //case1 - output
     //console.log(data);//1

     //case2 - output 
     console.log(data);//{id:1,name:joe}
     console.log(data.id);//1 
     console.log(data.name);//joe                 
}
</script>
```

In signin I dont know how session works in zend but in corePHP it goes as shown below..

```
<?php

public function signindo()
{
    //case 1
    //session_start();
    //$_SESSION['id'] = 1; //Not in small $_Session
    //echo $_SESSION['id'];

    //case 2
    $test_array = array('id'=>1,'name'=>'joe');
    echo json_encode($test_array);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function signindo()
{
    $namespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace(); 
    $namespace->id = 1;
    echo $namespace->id;
    exit;
}
```

Client side:

```
$.post("/user/signindo",{'username':username,"password":password},function(data){    
//data will be your session id
}
```

*Read the below link for more details about Zend session*

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html

Comment: I have another value stored in data... its a constant and I call it like this: 

$this->dieCustomerCode(Constant::SUCCESS); 

 protected function dieCustomerCode($statusCode){
     echo $statusCode;
     die();
    }

Does any of this makes sense?

Comment: If you have more than values need to return from server then store the values into an array and json_encode the array.
$response = array('val1' => 1, 'val2' => 2);
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($response);
exit();

Comment: Client side you can access data like this.
var objData = eval(data);
var value1 = objData.val1;
var value2 = objData.val2;